# Issue with Token in createAndSend function

Tags: docusignapi

I have been building some pdf forms and using docusign for signatures. The issue I am having with the current one is that docusign goes to "finished" after my 2nd signer signs. The logs show that it is not sending to my 3rd signer but I am unsure how to code the getToken to include the 3rd signer after the 2nd has signed.
Any advice would be very helpful.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

//$GLOBALS['_oneSigner'] = isset($_POST["autorefill"]);

createAndSend();

    if(!$GLOBALS['_oneSigner']){
        $GLOBALS['_showTwoSignerMessage'] = true;
    }
} else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {

if (isset($_GET["envelopeID"])) {
        // Display a message that we are moving on to Signer Number 2
        // - unless the message is suppressed (by signing from the GetStatusAndDocs page)


        if(isset($_GET['from_gsad'])){
            getToken(getStatus($_GET['envelopeID']),$_GET['clientID']);

        }else{
            $GLOBALS['_showTransitionMessage'] = true;
        getToken(getStatus($_GET['envelopeID']),2);

    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["embedToken"] = "";
}
}
```

Comment: Putting the code above aside for a moment, the symptom you are describing sounds like the envelope only has 2 signers assigned to it as opposed to 3. Is the envelope in a "Completed" state after signer2 signs? If so, i'd recommend sharing a snippet of your envelope creation JSON/XML for extra eyes.

Comment: You are correct actually, I went back and did it a little bit different to where it sends emails instead of the in person signer. This issue was setting a signer id # caused it to register as in person, and not send the email.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an email sending and using "Embedded Signing" you need to specify a clientUserId that would tell DocuSign not to send the email and instead expect a call to generate embedded signing url.
See complete code example here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding